# too much data on one chart.js (line)

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am coming up with a simple question. After some time I have a lot of data and I would like to present only every 10th value on the chart.

I am using the CHART.JS plugin.

I tried to test that code:

```
plugins: {
   datalabels: {
       align: 'top',
       color: '#000000',
       font: {
            weight: 'bold',
            size: '16'
       },
       formatter: (value, context) =>  context.chart.data.datasets[0].data.length < 100 || context.dataIndex % 10 == 0 ? value : '' 
   }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention. It is not working. Any other idea?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: Your code works fine, but you have to return `null` when you don't want a label, the empty string is creating an empty label. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3vdteom0/1/) that I had to make in order to test your code. Making such a reproducible example yourself would help getting an answer fast.